# BitBucket readme markdown and unordered list

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, readme

Well - in the git README.md I have

```
## Release Notes

2017-09-25
* Errors reporting to the back-end
* added contact info phone number extension (as optional)

2017-09-22
* Error messages
* Initial full release
```

it displays fine in the github but not on the BitBucket README.md where `*` is not working as a unordered list item.

Any thoughts?

Comment: add a line break between date and first item of the list

Comment: @gogaz that did the job. Thanks! you can post as a answer

Comment: @JackTheKnife - an empty comment just before the list does the trick for me too - `<!-- -->`

Comment: too late, it's already been answered :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try adding a blank line just before the `*` list items. Something like this:

```
2017-09-25

* Errors reporting to the back-end
* added contact info phone number extension (as optional)
```

Bitbucket's MarkDown viewer is not as advanced as Github's viewer.